# Create column in pandas based on two other columns and table

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

```
table = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
                 columns=['High','Middle','Low'],
                index=['Blue','Green','Red'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['High','Blue'],
                    ['High','Green'],
                    ['Low','Red'],
                   ['Middle','Blue'],
                    ['Low','Blue'],
                    ['Low','Red']],
             columns=['A','B'])

>>> df
        A      B
0    High   Blue
1    High  Green
2     Low    Red
3  Middle   Blue
4     Low   Blue
5     Low    Red

>>> table
       High  Middle  Low
Blue      1       2    3
Green     4       5    6
Red       7       8    9
```

I'm trying to add a third column 'C' which is based on the values in the table. So the first row would get a value of 1, the second of 4 etc.

If this would be be a one-dimensional lookup I would convert the table to a dictionary and would use `df['C'] = df['A'].map(table)`. However since this is two-dimensional I can't figure out how to use map or apply.

Ideally I would convert the table to dictionary format so I save it together with other dictionaries in a json, however this is not essential.

Comment: If what you're after is a mapping of your `table` values to categorical pairs in `df` why don't you try the following: `table.unstack().reset_index()`. This will melt your table down into the 9 values you want to manipulate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pandas` `lookup`

```
table.lookup(df.B,df.A)
Out[248]: array([1, 4, 9, 2, 3, 9], dtype=int64)

#table['c']=table.lookup(df.B,df.A)
```

Or `df.apply(lambda x : table.loc[x['B'],x['A']],1)` personally do not like `apply`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `merge` for this:

```
df2 = (df.merge(table.stack().reset_index(),
                left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['level_1', 'level_0'])
       .drop(['level_0', 'level_1'], 1)
       .rename(columns={0:'C'}))

>>> df2
        A      B  C
0    High   Blue  1
1    High  Green  4
2     Low    Red  9
3     Low    Red  9
4  Middle   Blue  2
5     Low   Blue  3
```